# LWC is not showing up in Record page for Knowledge Record Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to Create a LWC to attache multiple cases to an Knowledge article , But when i am going to Knowldege Record Page the Lwc is not showing up in the Custom Components Drop down. I have configured the Knowledge__kav object in target Config .

```
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
             <objects>
             <object>Knowledge__kav</object>
              <object>Case</object>     
          </objects>
        </targetConfig>
```

Answer (score 4):

We built something similar in the past, and we had to modify the component's configuration file as follow:

1. Set isExposed to true, to allow the component to be used in Lightning App Builder,
2. Define the target called lightning__RecordPage to enable the component to be used on a record page in Lightning App Builder.

This is an example of how the component configuration file should look like after making those changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="TestLWC">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <!-- additional configurations go here -->
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

The configuration file is located within the Lightning web component folder and it is named .js-meta.xml.

You can find more information about the configuration file and its tags [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags).

Hope it helps.